# Create Azure VM with artifact switch

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli, azure-devtest-labs

I'm trying to create a VM via the CLI and add an artifact from the public repo in a dev test lab.

Here is my script:
`az lab vm create --resource-group TestRG --lab-name TestLab --name 'ScriptVM' --image "Windows 10 Pro, Version 1809" --image-type gallery --size 'Standard_B2s' --admin-username 'user' --admin-password 'pw' --artifacts '{ "/artifactsources/publicrepo/artifacts/linux-java" }'`

I don't know the format of the artifacts switch though as it just says a JSON encoded array. How does this work? I just get the error 
`Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was I didn't have all the required elements in the JSON. I also fell foul of escaping quotation marks in the PS script. The final switch ended up looking like this:`--artifacts '[{"""artifactId""": """artifacts/windows-notepadplusplus"""}]'`

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows the sections that make up the basic structure of a definition file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-devtestlab/master/schemas/2016-11-28/dtlArtifacts.json",
  "title": "",
  "description": "",
  "iconUri": "",
  "targetOsType": "",
  "parameters": {
    "<parameterName>": {
      "type": "",
      "displayName": "",
      "description": ""
    }
  },
  "runCommand": {
    "commandToExecute": ""
  }
}
```

It resides in your **Git repo** and is referenced in the AZ command.  A video of the entire process can be found in our documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/devtest-lab-artifact-author